# Table getting locked for >1 simultaneous transaction

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have >1 transaction accessing a single table in a particular scenario (SELECT and UPDATE). I can see in pg_locks view with query

```
SELECT relation::regclass, * 
FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT granted;
```

that till the lock is held(my 2nd transaction is blocked) this query gives me result. After my 2nd transaction starts proceeding this entry is lost. So i am assuming this table is telling me about lock.

But i want to confirm which table is getting locked if my above assumption is correct. And how can i resolve this issue because this is creating a performance issue for my application in case of large data.

Comment: Please show the full statements that (b)lock each other. With the information you have given this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Show the actual `pg_locks` lines, too. Otherwise we don't know what you're looking at. I'd say you're seeing different lock types.

Comment: select pg_class.relname,pg_locks.* from pg_class,pg_locks where pg_class.relfilenode=pg_locks.relation and mode like '%RowExclusive%' ; gave me what i was looking for.